# Wait-free or lock-free initialization

Tags: c++

I've been looking at lazy initialization (let's say- global variables, but it could be of anything). So far, what I've come up with is something like

```
enum state {
    uninitialized,
    initializing,
    initialized
};
state s;
char memory[sizeof(T)];
T& initialize() {
    auto val = compare_and_swap(&s, state::uninitialized, state::initializing);
    if (val == initialized)
        return *(T*)memory;
    if (val == initializing) {
        while(atomic_read(&s) != state::initialized);
        return *(T*)memory;
    }
    new (memory) T();
    atomic_write(&s, state::initialized);
    return *(T*)memory;
}
```

In the case where it's already been initialized, then it's wait-free. But I've got a problem with the case where one thread is initializing. The number of steps required to finish initializing or wait for initialization to finish isn't proportional to the number of threads. But if the initializing thread is paused, the other threads all have to wait arbitrarily until it's resumed. So in the general case it's not lock-free or wait-free.

Is it possible to create lazy initialization which is wait-free or lock-free?

Comment: This code isn't even lock-free...

Comment: It's clearly not lock free. That's the source of the question. If I had lock-free lazy initialization, why would I ask a question asking about if it's possible?

Comment: Fair enough; I was thrown off by the complex code - if you just wanted a locking lazy initialization, you could have used a `static` variable and be done with it.

Comment: The code would also need `alignas(alignof(T))`, and it would cause undefined behaviour if the destructor of `T` has side effects and you don't have a suitable cleanup :-(

Comment: Ah no, this is what I've got so far, which is nice and fast in the simple case. But the weak initialization semantics in the initializing case are unfortunate. And yes, I skipped over those details because they're not really relevant.

Comment: Your code will live-lock if `T` construction throws an exception.

Comment: Good catch. I wasn't planning on actually using this any time soon but it's worth keeping such things in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to initialize more than one object, then you can make lockfree code by only storing a pointer:

```
std::atomic<T *> p { nullptr };

T & get()
{
    T * q = p.load();
    if (!q)
    {
        T * r = new T;
        if (p.compare_exchange_strong(q, r))
        {
            return *r;
        }
        else
        {
            delete r;
            return *q;
        }
    }
    return *q;
}
```

The cost of lock-free algorithms is that you generally have to "try and fail", so you have to pay the price of trying locally even if you have to discard the result.

As you rightly pointed out, if only a single thread performs the initialization, you always depend on that single thread, and you cannot be lock-free.

---

You will need corresponding clean-up code, too, if the destructor has side effects:

```
delete p.exchange(nullptr);
```

Comment: Is the approach I just came up with. Strictly, isn't this algorithm also wait-free?

Comment: @DeadMG: You cannot ever depend on any single thread if you want to be lock-free. The whole purpose of being lock-free is that you can make progress even if an arbitrary number of threads are stopped indefinitely.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to use fibers or some other technique to "steal" a half-completed initialization from another blocked thread.

Comment: @DeadMG: Unlikely in the general case. Fibers require cooperation from the user code.

Comment: I guess that if you consider a thread that was blocked by an external resource- let's say arbitrarily loading a web page- then it cannot be resumed. So it's impossible for you to resume it. So as long as the lazy initialization is arbitrary, then it cannot be lock-free.

Comment: It just occurred to me that this also cannot be wait (or lock) free if `operator new` is not wait (or lock) free. I wonder what the wait/lock free guarantees of `new` are?

Comment: @DeadMG: That's true - you need a suitably lock-free memory allocator. An interesting problem? :-) Maybe preallocate a large chunk of static memory, and treat it as a no-producer/multi-consumer list?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt have thought either is possible in the general case. If you did this as part of global initialization, before main is called and before the threads are created, then you stand a chance. How can it be wait-free or lock-free?

It could be lock-free if you allow the initialise to fail and retry later.
It cant be wait-free if another thread has the item.

If you care about the performance here, then you could use the thread id to hash into a bucket of items, to try and reduce the frequency of contention.